# Cassinian like Ovals known?

Tags: geometry, locus

Focal points $ A,B $ are at distance $ 2 c $ apart. Find locus of a point $P$ so that sum of reciprocals of $AP,BP$  is a constant $ 2/a, a $ is the harmonic mean of these segments. Resemblance is to Cassinian ovals where their *product* is constant.

$$ \frac{1}{\sqrt{ (x-c)^2 + y^2}} + \frac{1}{\sqrt{ (x+c)^2 + y^2} }= \frac2a $$

[image: Cassinian like Ovals]

Comment: see (https://www.quora.com/What-is-the-graph-of-the-mathematical-curve-when-the-sum-of-the-inverse-distances-from-2-points-is-kept-constant)

Comment: Ok, so no historical names.

Comment: It looks so. Why not take the opportunity to name them Narasimham curves ?

Comment: :) ..  I am putting a related question about optic/geometrical properties. ..http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1935374/conics-definition-from-lens-formula

Comment: It is a spiric section: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spiric_section

Comment: @Aretino: As mentioned in the [Quora link given above](https://www.quora.com/What-is-the-graph-of-the-mathematical-curve-when-the-sum-of-the-inverse-distances-from-2-points-is-kept-constant), the polynomial representation of the relation has degree 8. Spiric sections only have degree 4.

Comment: @Blue Exceptional level curve that makes Figure of 8 making  saddle point at center has degree eight. Rest of all level curves have a degree four.

Comment: @Narasimham: Interesting. Well, I'll leave my comment up, in case others have are in need of this clarification.

Comment: @ Jean Marie: I do not know whether any physics of gravity like forces is involved here to be considered of scientific interest. ( Btw, Cassini thought the original ovals named after him were planetary orbits, later disproved by Newton etal.)